# Read Input form Barcode-Scanner with C and hide the Input from the OS

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, device

I have a Barcode-Scanner that behave like a keyboard. I want to read the input with a c-program and hide the input from the OS.

I don't want to use a combination of Input-Events and Hooks (like in this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective), because that is way to slow.

I found this example (http://www.oblita.com/interception.html), that is reading from the keyboard-device (I think). It is working perfect, but it requires an installation-routine, and I don't know, what this routine is doing. Maybe its harmful, so I don't want to use that. But I want to know how this installation-routine is working.

Comment: All that the Interception folks have done is written a driver. You can do that, too. But the claim that Raw Input is "way too slow" is quite strange. It should not be slow. I don't have time to go through that entire Code Project article, but the only thing I can think of is that the slowness is caused from their doing something wrong.

Comment: The `RAWINPUTHEADER` comes with a handle to the device that sent the input, which you can use with [`GetRawInputDeviceInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597.aspx) to get the device name, which you can use to decide whether to accept or ignore the input. No hooks required. And raw input is as fast as you can process the `WM_INPUT` messages.

Comment: The statement that [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) is *"way to[o] slow"* is unfounded. How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: I did not say that Raw Input is slow, but the combination of Input and Hooks is. That is because, and now a cite from the microsoft-page: Hooks tend to slow down the system because they increase the amount of processing the system must perform for each message. You should install a hook only when necessary, and remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: And to block input from a certain device I need to use hooks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "hide the input from the OS"?

Comment: Have you measured the performance and concluded, that using a hook is inhibitively slow? Besides, from [WM_INPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx): *"If an application processes this message, it should return zero."*

Comment: @theB: the Raw Input API can differentiate between multiple devices, but it cannot block input from being processed. A keystroke that the scanner generates will be sent to the current window that has input focus, unless a keyboard hook blocks it. A hook cannot differentiate between devices, though. So a combination of Raw Input and keyboard hook is needed to detect scanner input and block it from being sent to other apps. However, this would only be needed if the hooking app does not have input focus, otherwise blocking the input is unnecessary.

Comment: @IInspectable: returning a non-zero value in response to `WM_INPUT` does not prevent the input from being forwarded down the chain, thus the window with input focus can receive the scanner's keystrokes even if it does not know what to do with them. It will think they are normal keystrokes as if the user had typed them by hand. That is not the case when dealing with barcode scanners, though.  So, if the hooking app does not have input focus, it needs to intercept the scanner input and block it from being received by other apps.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks, perfectly explained :)

Comment: @IInspectable I have took the example and ran it on my PC. It was slowing down the whole system. That effect only shows if someone types really fast.

Comment: @Andre: It very much looks like the sample code is not ideal. For one, it calls `SendMessage` from its hook procedure. That means two additional (costly) context switches for each input event.